# The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-3, maven-plugin, nexus

this is my environment. 
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.5.4
Nexus 2.14.8-01
Jenkins 2.136

my issue is I cannot perform a mvn clean deploy in Jenkins without it issuing error. the error:

---

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 in http://137.27.68.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ge-ip-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I'm rather new, and each experience brings me closer, but, I'm baffled.

In Nexus Maven Central, I look in Nexus repo, and under Browse Index, the maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 exists, however, under browse storage, only 2.8.2 exists.

I'm not specifying or to my knowledge a specific version and wonder why doesn't it just use the maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.8.2 ??? instead of the 2.7. and I can't find where the 2.7 is being declared. ??

thank you any suggestions on how to resolve or explain what the heck is going on would be much appreciated, IOU beer and more beer. :)

SETTINGS FOR JENKINS

```
<settings
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <!-- The path to the local repository -->
  <localRepository>/Users/212555427/devel/maven/repositories/ge-ip-jenkins-repository</localRepository>

  <offline>false</offline>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>com.ge.ip.snapshot.local</id>
      <username>xxxxx</username>
      <password>xxxxxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>

    <mirror>
      <id>ge-ip-nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus Repository Manager</name>
      <mirrorOf>*,!jbossRepos(x)</mirrorOf> 
      <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
    </mirror>

  </mirrors>

  <profiles>

    <!-- A definition of a development profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>development</id>
      <repositories>

        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>com.ge.ip.release</id>
          <name>Release Repository</name>
          <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
        </repository>

        <!-- The specified location of where all snapshot artifacts are retrieved from.  -->

        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>com.ge.ip.snapshot</id>
          <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
        </repository>

      </repositories>

      <pluginRepositories>

        <!-- The specified location of where all released plugins are retrieved from.  -->

        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>com.ge.ip.plugin.release</id>
          <name>Plugin Release Repository</name>
          <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
        </pluginRepository>

        <!-- The specified location of where all snapshot plugins are retrieved from.  -->

        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>com.ge.ip.plugin.snapshot</id>
          <name>Plugin Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
        </pluginRepository>

      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <!-- Specify the default active profile. -->
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>development</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ge.digital.fleet</groupId>
  <artifactId>ge.digital.fleet.parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>




 <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>DIGITAL Fleet Parent</name>

  <properties>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <compiler.source.version>1.8</compiler.source.version>
    <compiler.target.version>1.8</compiler.target.version>

    <!-- JBoss Fuse Properties -->
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.3.0.redhat-310</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <jboss.fuse.install>6.3.0.redhat-310</jboss.fuse.install>

    <!-- Versions pulled from JBoss Fuse BOM for Dependency Management. -->
    <cxf-version>2.17.0.redhat-630310</cxf-version>
    <camel-version>2.17.0.redhat-630310</camel-version>
    <activemq-version>5.11.0.redhat-630310</activemq-version>
    <karaf-version>2.4.0.redhat-630310</karaf-version>
    <hawtio-version>1.4.0.redhat-630310</hawtio-version>
    <fabric-version>1.2.0.redhat-630310</fabric-version>
    <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    <velocity-bundle-version>2.17.0.redhat-630310</velocity-bundle-version> 
    <velocity-version>2.17.0.redhat-630310</velocity-version>
    <joda-time-version>2.9.2</joda-time-version>

    <!-- Versions of 3rd Party Dependencies -->
    <ibm-mq-version>7.5.0.8</ibm-mq-version>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <ftpserver-version>1.0.6</ftpserver-version>
    <sshd-version>0.10.0</sshd-version>
    <greenmail-version>1.4.0</greenmail-version>

    <!-- Plugin Versions-->
    <version.maven-compiler-plugin>2.5.1</version.maven-compiler-plugin>
    <bundle-plugin-version>2.3.7</bundle-plugin-version>
    <build-helper-plugin-version>1.8</build-helper-plugin-version>
    <resources-plugin-version>2.4.3</resources-plugin-version>
    <felix-bundle-plugin-version>2.3.7</felix-bundle-plugin-version>
    <lifecycle-mapping-version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping-version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin-version>2.8.1</maven-failsafe-plugin-version>
    <depends-maven-plugin-version>1.2</depends-maven-plugin-version>

  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Import Fuse Dependency Management via BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.21</version>  <!-- 5.7.21 5.1.27-->
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1_5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.9_2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
          <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
 </dependencies>     

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${compiler.source.version}</source>
          <target>${compiler.target.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <!-- 
    TODO
    The url needs to be updated to the Corporate Nexus Instance.
    This includes the hostname, port, and directory structure.
    The <id> must match the <server> id in the settings.xml.
    The settings.xml will contain the username/password.
    Also note that only Jenkins should be doing the deploy, therefore
    developer settings.xml SHOULD NOT contain the user name / password
    of the <server>
   -->

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>com.ge.ip.snapshot.local</id>
      <name>GE IP Releases</name>
      <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>com.ge.ip.snapshot.local</id>
      <name>GE IP Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://137.277.686.182:8082/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: sorry failed to mention, this was all working at one point. with other versions. my laptop crashed and I lost everything. so, installed fairly new versions of things. trying to get things back. seems maven 3.5 has many restrictions and changes.

Comment: I guess the question to ask is what determines the "maven-deploy-plugin" version?  when "clean deploy" is issued in Jenkins, and there is no declaration of the deployment plugin in any POM. does anyone understand what determines the plugin version?  can it be any of these:    <version.maven-compiler-plugin>2.5.1</version.maven-compiler-plugin>
    <bundle-plugin-version>2.3.7</bundle-plugin-version> 
    <build-helper-plugin-version>1.8</build-helper-plugin-version>
    <resources-plugin-version>2.4.3</resources-plugin-version>

Comment: I'm thinking this may be a BUG or a Maven versioning thing.  If I force Jenkins to deploy with the command. clean package org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy  it works. otherwise, a simple "clean deploy" Maven looks for deploy plugin 2.7 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a version/release for deployment plugin

clean package org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy

Answer (score 1):

Does a direct download work?

http://137.27.68.182:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.17.pom

If it doesn't, examine the nexus.log file. You'll likely find the network connection from Nexus to Maven Central isn't working for some reason (e.g., it may be getting blocked by your firewall).

Comment: thanks rseddon, really appreciate your feedback. I think I confused the question.  If I ( in Jenkins ) perform a "mvn clean deploy" maven looks for deployment plugin version 2.7 - which is not in the repo. however, ver 2.8.2 is in the repo. if I ( in Jenkins ) issue clean package org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy it works.  Why doesn't Maven simply use the 2.8.2 version ? there must be some way that there are specific plugin versions associated with other mechanisms like bundle-plugin-helper or resources-plugin, etc.. IDK. it is like pulling teeth to find the answer.

Comment: another mystery is that in Nexus repo mgr, the maven central repo ( in Browse Index tab ) has all the deployment plugins in it.  on the maven central repo ( in the Browse Storage tab )  it only has the 2.8 version.   ??? what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

well, the reason for inability to access repos in nexus is due to company vpn security - not sure if it is the proxy or certs at this point.

but, If anyone knows how Maven determines the plugin releases or versions please post an answer.  for instance if you simply issue a mvn clean deploy - how does maven know to pick deploy plugin 2.7 or 2.8 ?

thank you!